# How to inverse differencing on future forecasted result?

Tags: python, time-series

I'm preparing a time series model with ARIMA, I noticed that the time series data is not stationary so I used diff(period=1) in pandas. I fitted the ARIMA model and it looks good. When we are forecasting for test values and in real time, how to inverse the predictions because the original data is not available?
In fact, I want to invers the prediction that I calculated by below code?

```
y_transformed = y.diff().dropna() #y is orginal dataset
nobs=12
train, test = y_transformed[0:-nobs], y_transformed[-nobs:]

# Fit ARMA model
model = ARMA(train['Sales'],order=(2,2))
ARMAfit = model.fit()

# Prediction for test values
start=len(train)
end=len(train)+len(test)-1
predictions = ARMAfit.predict(start=start , end=end, dynamic=False).rename('ARMA `Predictions')`
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code posted by another user on Github:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/41326

`def diff_inv(series_diff, first_value):`

`series_inverted = np.r_[first_value,series_diff].cumsum().astype('float64')`

`return series_inverted`

In my opinion, the way to look at it intuitively, is that since all data is differenced (original + predictions), you could argue that the predictions have the same structure as the original differenced data. Predictions are just estimates right? Not perfect or hard factual data. Hence, if they carry the same "structure" as the originally differenced data, then it would be reasonable to take the last value of the original data (not differenced) and use it as your "first_value" in the above function.

Hope this works for you!